Avoid not private connection via PowerShell
I've created powershell script which open particular url. Now I have a problem: before openning this url I've got a pop-up with information about 'Your connection is not private'. How to avoid this security task?
#paths to Chromium needed executables 
$Chromium="C:\Program` Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
#...
# some code
#...

elseif ($i -eq 5)
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath $Chromium -ArgumentList '--kiosk "https://192.168.1.1/dashboard/"' 
        $CurrentActionLabel.text="Current action: Starting HMI main process..."
        $BootForm.Refresh()        

        do 
        {
            $processHMI = Get-Process viewer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        until ($processHMI -ne $null)
        $CurrentActionLabel.text="Current action: HMI main process started..."

error screen
